Clarification on electronic configuration of Nickel, Palladium and Platinum
So, atoms prefer fully-filled and half-filled configurations in orbitals that have $l$≥1 (p, d, f, etc.) due to higher exchange energy. This is why Cr has a configuration of 3d5 4s1 and not 3d4 4s2, and Pd has 4d10 5s0, and Cu has 3d10 4s1. However, why does Ni not follow this trend and have a configuration of 3d10 4s0, and instead has a (perhaps less stable, I believe) configuration of 3d8 4s2?
There is a similar question out there : Why is the ground state electronic configuration of Group 10 (Ni group) elements so anomalous?. However, it does not have any satisfactory answers. For example, by the logic it gives, Cr must have an electronic configuration of 3d4 4s2 by blandly stating that "So, for instance, in the fourth period we see 3d orbitals filled only after 4s in neutral atoms", without taking into account the atom's quest for greater stability through exchange energy. Hence, it doesn't explain Nickel's configuration. Next, it says this: "But by the time we get to the later transition metals the effective nuclear charge has increased even in the neutral atoms, the lower-n d subshell drops relative to the higher-n
s subshell, and we begin to see a greater preference for the d
subshell being filled first. By the time we get to Group 12, this transition is complete and only the s electrons remain valence electrons except, possibly, in extreme circumstances." This also does not explain the anomalous observations of the electronic configuration of Platinum (I feel that there is actually no true actual answer given in this answer to that question), and for why only Palladium has a d10 4s0 configuration while Platinum is d9 4s1. Hence, I've asked this question to get a clear answer as to why this occurs.

This question is similar to: Why is the ground state electronic configuration of Group 10 (Ni group) elements so anomalous?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Mithoron I didn't come across this post while searching for similar questions. However, the question you have posted does not have any satisfactory answers. I'll specify why.

@Mithoron I've edited the question to include an explanation as to why I feel those answers were not satisfactory. Also, I would like to point out that question did not seem very accessible as when I first searched for a similar question and when I typed out my question, this particular question did not pop up, leading me, and perhaps others out there too, to believe that no such question was there regarding this.

I would like to point out that if searching here was so easy, then I'd lose one of my main ways to waste time here ;>

Also names of elements aren't capitalised.
